# Dataframe drop rows where multiple columns have the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

My dataframe has the columns `A, B, C, label1, label2, label3`. I just want to drop the rows where label1 = label2 = label3. The label value can be `0, 1, 2, 3 and nan`
The best solution I've found so far is this

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['label1'] == df['label2']) & (df['label1'] == df['label3'])].index)
```

Is there any other way I could solve this problem since the code above feels wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solution for working with multiple columns by list is possible filter them first and then compare if not equal all filtered values in `df1` by first column with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for filter all rows if not same values - it is same like drop rows with same values:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  label1  label2  label3
0  4  5  6       0       0       0
1  1  2  3       7       4       5

df1 = df[['label1','label2', 'label3']]

df = df[df1.ne(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B  C  label1  label2  label3
1  1  2  3       7       4       5
```